# Keyboard in alphabetical sequence (ABC layout keyboard)

Tags: keyboard

I am considering buying a Samsung Galaxy phone. Is there an option (either basic phone function or a third party app) which provides a keyboard in alpha sequence, that is ABC layout instead of QWERTY?

Answer (score 7):

The stock Android keyboard doesn't have ABC layout. However, there are some keyboard apps which have ABC layout. [SlideIT English - ABC pack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dasur.language.ena.pack) is an example. You can find some more if you  [search for "ABC keyboard" on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=abc%20keyboard&c=apps).

Comment: `The stock Android keyboard doesn't have ABC layout.` is wrong as my SE Xperia mini supports it.

Comment: Or I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Probably isn't the stock android keyboard then ;)

Comment: @avirk: Your manufacturer likely added their own keyboard which does support ABC layout.  The *stock* Android keyboard (as of 4.2) supports QWERTY, QWERTZ, AZERTY, Dvorak, [Colemak](http://colemak.com/), and "[PC](http://unleashthephones.com/2012/10/31/hidden-gem-pc-layout-in-leaked-android-4-2-keyboard/)" layout, but not ABC.

Comment: @avirk: The keyboard you have mentioned is not stock Android keyboard. I reckon that is "Xperia™ keyboard" However, the latest version of Xperia Keyboard (found on newer phones like Xperia S) doesn't have ABC layout either. I have an Xperia Neo V and I have flashed Xperia Keyboard from Xperia S system apps, so I have confirmed this on my device.

Answer (score 4):

There is a keyboard available that is on the app store, it is designed for dyslexics who have difficulty in recognizing the letters, the problem with the QWERTY layout is that dyslexics cannot "see" the letters and looking all over the keyboard for it, have a mate who suffers from it, and this was born out of the idea when I watched him struggle with the touch keyboard.

This keyboard is actually from stock AOSP Gingerbread source, with letters re-arranged into ABC layout.

It is available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=t0mm13b.keyboard4dyslexics) on Play store.

**Edit:** Disclosure, I am the person responsible for the aforementioned app.

Comment: You should disclose any affiliation you have with this app per the [FAQ#promotion].

Comment: @Al Everett -Sorry I put in the disclosure in place, to hopefully clarify my affiliation with the app.

Comment: That's fine. That's all we ask.

Answer (score 0):

The stock, AOSP Android keyboard does not have the ABC 'old fashioned' keyboard layout, however some manufacturers package their own IME (keyboard), that comes with this feature.

Some manufactures are LG, and Sony Ericsson that do this (Sony Ericsson Xperia devices do).

AFAIK the stock Samsung IME doesn't come with this option - however, you can download 3rd-party IME's that have this layout format.

Answer (score 0):

I published an alphabetical keyboard that's now available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arise.alphabeticalkeyboard) and Androidfreeware.net.